# CSS: Stylesheet not reflecting changes

Tags: html, css, browser-cache

I am creating a custom page on WordPress using a child theme, but when I make changes to the stylesheet on my site, and I refresh the site, none of the changes are reflected. When I check the file in my file manager, it definitely is updated. I manually set the encoding to UTF-8.

Previously it had updated after about an hour, but now it didn't even change overnight.
This led me to believe that the stylesheet was cached, so I cleared my cache and reloaded using `CTRL + F5`.

I've also added `?ver=<?php echo rand(111,999)?>` to the end of my stylesheet link, so for time I am developing, it wouldn't cache the stylesheet.

None of this worked. (Edit: the error persists on all major browsers)

When I place my styles as internal CSS, it works just fine and changes are reflected immediately. So far, I've tried all the solutions I could find, so if there's something, I've overlooked, please tell me!

dashboard.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dashboard.css?ver=<?php echo rand(111,999)?>" />
    </head>
```

dashboard.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";

.container {
    width: 1200px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}

...
```

The file directory looks like this (it's all in the same folder):

```
[Theme Folder]
-dahboard.css
-dashboard.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include ./ on the dashboard.css file.
So the code will look like

```
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./dashboard.css?ver=<?php echo rand(111,999)?>" />
    </head>
```

Answer (score -1):

Disabled cache in your browser, and if it still doesn't work, try using another browser

Comment: Please read the question again. The OP clearly said, that he already cleared the cache aswell as he preventing a cache in the first place. Also, if the issue would be caused by a cache issue, this question would not fit SO (not reproduciable or caused by typo) and as such shouldn't be answered.